# SQLite UPDATE with Shell script

Tags: shell, sqlite

I am really new to SQLite.
I want to update BLOBs in the Column "data" in my database and i got it working:
UPDATE genp SET data= X'MyHexData' WHERE rowid=510849
As i want to update multiple BLOBs from the Column data i decited to write a .sh script:

sqlite3 my.db 'UPDATE genp SET data= X'MyHexData' WHERE rowid=510849'

When i execute this script i get the error message: 
SQL error: no such column: XMyHexData

Why does SQLite think that my hex data is supposed to be the column? Where is my mistake? It works if i run this in the Command Line Shell of SQLite.

EDIT:
I got it working.Like this:

sqlite3 my.db "UPDATE genp SET data= X'MyHexData' WHERE rowid= '510849'"

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used single quotes to quote the argument. Escape them.

```
... '...\'...'
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I see what you mean. I cant use single quotes within single quotes just like that. But can you please explain how to escape them in my code specificly? I dont really know how to... I have tried it like this: `sqlite3 my.db 'UPDATE genp SET data= X\’MyHexData\’ WHERE rowid=510849'` But it gives me a error: `./load.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file` I hope you can help me and thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: I got it working. See the edit in my question. Thanks for your help